# JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile getting GC overhead error for large datasource

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Please, consider the following code snippet -

```
JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(jasperReportBeanList);
String printFileName = JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(templateFilePath, parameters, beanColDataSource);
```

Here , jasperReportBeanList containing over 250000 records. Now, at the time of executing `JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(templateFilePath, parameters, beanColDataSource)` method I am getting GC over exceeded error or out of memory error.

Please, note that I have also added the following line in my code -

```
DefaultJasperReportsContext context = DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance();
JRPropertiesUtil.getInstance(context).setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.executer.factory",
            "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.xml.JaxenXPathExecuterFactory");
```

But, still I am getting error.

Any help is appreciated.